# List to List conversion using automapper is not working in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

```
    public List<SpecificationAttributes> GetSpecificationAttributesList()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<List<SpecificationAttribute>, List<SpecificationAttributes>>();
        using(ShoppingCartEntities ent=new ShoppingCartEntities())
        {
            var resultSet = (from sa in ent.ProductSpecificationAttributes
                             select sa
                           ).ToList<SpecificationAttribute>();
            List<SpecificationAttributes> item=Mapper.Map<List<SpecificationAttribute>,List<SpecificationAttributes>>(resultSet);
            return item;
        }
    }
```

In this above function mapper returns blank.. I can not solve it out.. please help me..
resultSet has 5 items...but mapper returns blank..

Answer (score 3):

change

```
Mapper.CreateMap<List<SpecificationAttribute>, List<SpecificationAttributes>>();
```

To

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SpecificationAttribute, SpecificationAttributes>();
```

This should work for you if your models are right, for more details you may refer to [their documentation](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists%20and%20Arrays)

> AutoMapper only requires configuration of element types, not of any array or list type that might be used

Comment: Also `CreateMap` should only be called once per AppDomain, it likely should be in `Global.asax` instead of inside `GetSpecificationAttributesList()`